# не считает положительные, отрицательные и равные нулю элементы, выдает просто по нулям

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{   
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
   int i,a[100],n,j=0,k=0,l=0;
   printf(" Введите размер массива ");
scanf("%d", &n);
srand(time(NULL));
for (i=0; i< n; i++) 
{
a[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;
printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
 
     
   if (a[i] > 0) 
   {
    j++;
    } 
     else if (a[i] < 0) 
     {
      k++;
      }
       else if (a[i] = 0)
       {
        l++;    
        }
 
    

printf("\nПоложительных: %d", j);
printf("\nОтрицательных: %d", k);
printf("\nРавных нулю: %d", l);

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, сравнивайте, понимайте :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i, a[100], n, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
    printf(" Введите размер массива ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i< n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

        if (a[i] > 0)
        {
            j++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < 0)
        {
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            l++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nПоложительных: %d", j);
    printf("\nОтрицательных: %d", k);
    printf("\nРавных нулю: %d", l);
}
```

И учтите, что здесь

```
if (a[i] = 0)
```

вы *не сравниваете*, а *присваиваете*.

Comment: Блин, точно. Спасибо ^ ^